# How i can echo enum value from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, enums, echo

I have a table "members" with column called "Type"  and it is "enum" and the values are"member, mod, admin, dev".
I want to know how i can echo the enum value that i set to member by $_SESSION['type'] or even only by $type?
 Something like this

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT ID, PASSWORD, TYPE FROM members WHERE NICK = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['INick']);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $Type);
        $stmt->fetch();
        session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['tipo'] = $Type;
    } else {
        echo '<center>';
        echo 'No data found at that table!';
        echo '</br><button onclick="Refres();">refresh</button><center>';
    }

if($_SESSION['type'] !== "member"){
     echo '</br>';
     echo 'Your Account - '.$Type.' - do have level access to that page.';
     exit();
 }
```

it shows to me an error "Notice: Undefined variable: Type"

Comment: Is Type defined outside the loop even if set to null?

Comment: Never Mind I notice you call $Session['tipo'] shouldn't it be $Session['type']

Comment: @Shane i checked it and i changed it but nothing makes diference.